# Zabbix LLD custom process monitoring item error

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I want to track my custom processes through Zabbix (v2.4.8). I am generating the following json object and sending it through `UserParameter=service.value[*],/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts/custom1.bash`:

```
{
    "data":[

    {
        "{#NAME}":"ntp",
        "{#VALUE}":"1"
    },
    {
        "{#NAME}":"mysql",
        "{#VALUE}":"1"
    },
    {
        "{#NAME}":"prometheus",
        "{#VALUE}":"0"
    },
    {
        "{#NAME}":"apache2",
        "{#VALUE}":"0"
    }

    ]
}
```

Also, creating an item prototype and graph prototype inside a new template with a new discovery rule, having the following information:

```
Discovery rule name: Service Graph
Type: Zabbix Agent
key: service.value

Item Prototype name: Service {#NAME} Graph
Type: Zabbix Agent
key: service.value[{#NAME},{#VALUE}]
Type of info: Numeric(Unsigned) & Decimal
```

When I apply these settings, the items keep giving the following error:

`Not supported: Received value [{ "data":[ { "{#NAME}":"ntp", "{#VALUE}":"1" }, { "{#NAME}":"mysql", "{#VALUE}":"1" }, { "{#NAME}":"prometheus", "{#VALUE}":"0" }, { "{#NAME}":"apache2", "{#VALUE}":"0" } ]}] is not suitable for value type [Numeric (unsigned)] and data type [Decimal]`

I have to create a graph prototype with these settings, so I cannot mention type as "Text" for obvious reasons.

Another question: The graphs thus generated are not clickable at all like the other existing graphs.

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `service.value` key generates JSON, that should be used with the LLD rule only. You should not send any values in it. The key to be used in the prototypes should be like any normal key they only returns values it was asked for, do not use the LLD-generating key there.

Your current JSON looks like you might be able to use the built-in items for process monitoring, but that is hard to be sure about without additional detail.

Also note that `[*]` in the `UserParameter` definition is not needed if you do not pass parameters to this key.

Comment: So does this mean I keep the item prototype key the same as the rule key?

Comment: The opposite, having them the same makes no sense. One is to send JSON with the structure only, another - individual values.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I used "Calculated type" of item and a formula to pin-point the value. It was great help. Going forward, this will have a good use in creating Graph prototypes.